# Specifying word separator for double-click selection in ConEmu?

Tags: conemu

In ConEmu, when I double click on a line, it's going to select from the previous to the next white space. However, I'm looking for an option (if it exists) to specify word separators other than spaces.

For example, if I double-click on the "host" part below, only "host" is selected. If I double-click on "home", "/home/user/" is going to be selected. Any idea if it is possible to do this in ConEmu?

```
user@host:/home/user/
```