# Defining word delimiters for double-click selection in Msys2 in two terminal launchers

Tags: conemu, double-click, msys2

I am using Msys2, from PortableApps (I think this is not relevant), with the terminal launched via two possible cases (referred to below): (1) directly from the PortableApps launcher, (2) ConEmu.

**The problem**: I want to be able to choose the word delimiter, so I can change what I get copied when I double (left-)click and then middle-click elsewhere to paste (or Ctrl+v if pasting in a Windows application).

**Example 1**: I set my command prompt as

```
[myuser@mycomputer:/c/Users/...]$
```

I want to double-click anywhere in `/c/Users/...` and get that path selected for copy-pasting.
As of now, what I get copied is `myuser@mycomputer:/c/Users/...` (neither `@` or `:` are word delimiters for this purpose).
Any of the two cases (i.e., terminals, see above) get it wrong.

**Example 2**: If my command takes more than one line (given the width of my window) the end-of-line in the screen breaks whatever is copied.
If I have (note that the command line is broken due to the window width)

```
[myuser@mycomputer:/c/Users/...]$ cp -p ~/dir1/my_directory/fil
e_pattern1.dat target_dir
```

and double-click anywhere in `~/dir1/my_directory/fil`, that is what I get copied.
If I double-click anywhere in `e_pattern1.dat`, that is what I get copied as well.
I want to get in both cases `~/dir1/my_directory/file_pattern1.dat`.

Case (1) gets this right, case (2) gets it wrong.

**Example 3**: If I have

```
[myuser@mycomputer:/c/Users/...]$ ls -F
myscript*     mydir/     myfile.txt
```

(`-F` may append a character to each item, `*` stands for executable, e.g.),
I want to double click on `myscript` and not get `*` included.

Case (1) gets this right, case (2) gets it wrong.

... But I do want to get `*` included if it is part of a file pattern.

Both cases (1) and (2) get it wrong (I do not know if any terminal gets this right).

**Note**: On the positive side, if I execute

```
[myuser@mycomputer:/c/Users/...]$ cd ~/Documents/
```

and then I double-click anywhere in `Documents`, I get `~/Documents` copied in case (1), and `~/Documents/` in case (2).
Any of the two are ok (even if I would like to choose this too).
Other terminals (e.g., Multi-Tabbed PuTTY) only copy `/Documents/`, at least in the default configuration.

**How can I do this?**

[This help page](https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsMarkCopy.html) doesn't help.

**Related**:

1. Only specific to ConEmu:
   [Specifying word separator for double-click selection in ConEmu?](https://superuser.com/questions/1005704/specifying-word-separator-for-double-click-selection-in-conemu)
2. https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/328
3. https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/1145
4. List item

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question.  Where do you want to double-click in msys2 shell?  Isn't a `TAB` key do what you want?

Comment: @tukan - Please see edited question and let me know if it is clear now.

Comment: Yes, much better now.  The current delimiter for double click is space or / (when it is last) in my msys2 shell.   Out of curiosity I tried your `cp -p ~/dir1/my_directory/fil
e_pattern1*.dat target_dir` nad it copied the  `~/dir1/my_directory/file_pattern1` (till the star).  Did you play with the `options/mouse`? (You have to right-click on the titlebar of your msys2 shell and select Opions...) There forth from top is Mouse configuration.  Try to uncheck an option `copy as rich text`.

Comment: @tukan - I was not aware of this setting, but it did not help. As for the asterisk, I see the same as you, and I edited the OP to be specific about this.

Comment: I see.  Well, you have to play around with the settings, I think that is the only option you have.