# Hyperlink that self closes?

Tags: google-search

I ran a Google search in FF 60 (PortableApps, under Win 10) `https://www.google.com/search?q=word+delimiters+conemu`.

One of the results is

[image]

The text of the result corresponds to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1362381/defining-word-delimiters-for-double-click-selection-in-msys2-in-two-terminal-lau?noredirect=1#comment2048836_1362381) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1005704/specifying-word-separator-for-double-click-selection-in-conemu) questions (the website may scrape the web).

The strange thing is that when I Ctrl+Click on it, it opens a new tab that closes itself after a couple of seconds.
If I simply click on it, it shows an empty page `https://ilo134ulih.com/rs4xwf9yi?key=027ed88f05536b6c1a41df968c0abb52` (my NoScript is not enabled for that domain).

With this description, is it likely unsafe to check such a link?

Answer (score 0):

With NoScript it should be relatively safe to open unknown website, so JavaScript
is disabled for websites you didn't explicitly trust.

In any case, I opened the website and find that it doesn't really work.
The page in the Google search comes up with some text that lost its formatting,
and when opening the root website `https://www.cornwallchurch.com/`
the whole thing such hangs and the tab has to be closed.
That website is not really functional.

So, yes, NoScript protects you well enough from unknown JavaScript,
on condition that it is set to distrust all non-trusted websites,
especially third-party.